# Python - Selenium : Submit form without opening new tab or new window

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I have :

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

I have some url : `driver.get(url)`

I have one form I want to submit :

```
elt = driver.find_element_by_class_name('special_class')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button').click()
```

This opens a new window and I want everything to happen in one window.

I may have to submit similar things many times and then parse the output.

Is there a way to stay in the same window ? I don't want to have many windows opened.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid there is nothing you can do if the button is opening new window after form submission. Only thing which comes to my mind is to use headless browser like PhantomJS - since you are doing web crawling you could appreciate the speed too. See [this](https://realpython.com/blog/python/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/) tutorial for Python.

But I actually remembered there is a workaround for this, you can set Firefox `browser.link.open_newwindow` to `1`, this should cause every new window to be opened in current one. However I am not sure if this will work well with HTML `form`.

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.link.open_newwindow", 1)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

See reference for this feature [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought maybe there was a parameter I could initialize at the beginning to avoid new windows to open.
I didn't know that PhantomJS would increase the speed of the crawl.
So far, I tried only Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: See my edit, I actually recalled a way how to do this.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I was looking for. Actually, this doesn't work as you said because of the form but I used driver.window_handles and driver.switch_to_window to handle the different windows. (And to have no more than two windows)

Answer (score 3):

This actually depends on how the form is submitted. If in the HTML the code has
`<form`...`id = someID`... `target = "_blank"`, and the form element has some identifier you can manually change this attribute.

This opens the form in a new window the next time it is submitted:

```
Browser.execute_script(
    'document.getElementById("someID").setAttribute("target", "_blank")'
)
```

If, as you asked, you need to have the form **not** open in a new window, simply change `_blank` to `_self`. (And, of course, `someID` is a placeholder for the actual form's ID)

`Browser` is the Selenium WebDriver, and this executes the javaScript code inside, which changes the form's attributes to the desired ones. If the form does not have a unique ID, it's possible that it has another identifying property.

Hope this helped! I found this out myself today.